# How to call print function in new window after page is loaded completly

Tags: angularjs

I have this part of code and main ide is to open partial view in new page and call print function for that partial view. What i able to do is to open new window and call print function, but i didnt succeed to render partial view...so my print function is blank.Can someone help me how can i do that?

```
$scope.ConfirmTicketPayOut = function (ticketPin, username) {
    $scope.pinTicket = ticketPin;
    localStorage.setItem("pin", ticketPin);
    accountDataProviderService.confirmTicketPayOut(ticketPin, username)
    .then(function (response) {

        $scope.confirmTicketPayOut = response;
        if ($scope.confirmTicketPayOut.Result == true) {

                    var w = $window.open('/print');

                    angular.element(w).ready('load', function () {
                        w.print();

                    });
               }
    });
}
```

I tried this : `$timeout(w.print(),0);` but no success

Answer (score 0):

On the element you want to wait use the directive `ng-init=""`.
In there you can call the function for printing.

```
$scope.print = function() {
    print();
}
```

And in the html `ng-init="print()"`.

Comment: @borraciaBlu Im not sure that i understand ... can u say where i need to put it in my code

Comment: actually your code is trying to wait `/load` right? so put in there the directive. Do you have a controller for that page ?

Comment: hmm what is happening now is that when i click on button it open new window with print option but page is not loaded...i get just blank page to print...if u know what i mean

Comment: what's the name of the partial view that you are trying to render ? put in ther e the directive.

Comment: when i do like u say i get in new window print option but without values just angularjs variables ....for example {{time}} and things like that

Comment: it not load values just page

Comment: it seem you don't have angular in those pages. Did you check the html in that page. did you define a route for `/print`? whay are you not using the $location service $location.path('/print')  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83125/discussion-between-none-and-borracciablu).